# How to reorder elements in a nd tensor in tensorflow without a loop?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

Consider two tensors: Ta = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]], Tb = [[True, False, True],[False, True, False]] in tensorflow. Tb denotes the positions of Ta where the values are allowed. I need to bring all the allowed values of Ta to left side which shall be like, Ta_ordered = [[1,3,2],[2,1,4]].

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. It is based on sorting elements in the necessary order and then using `tf.gather()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Ta = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]
Tb = [[True, False, True],[False, True, False]]
Ta, Tb = (tf.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in (Ta, Tb))
X, Y = Ta.shape
inds = tf.range(X * Y)
inds = tf.reshape(inds, (X, Y))
adj = tf.cast(Tb, tf.int32) * (X + 1)
inds -= adj # guarantees minimums for marked elements
inds = tf.argsort(inds)
output = tf.gather(Ta, inds, batch_dims=1)
```